# Chained payments with permissions 520003 Authentication failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I have problem with executing chained payment after obtaining permission from user. I have no troubles to get Access Token and Access Token Secret.

The code should work this way: User (personal type sandbox account) authorizes primary receiver (business type sandbox account) to take money from his account.
Primary receiver sends a part of the sum to the second receiver.

The code is written in ASP.NET MVC but I suppose it has nothing to do with the framework, I'm using PayPalAdaptivePaymentsSDK and PayPalPermissionsSDK

I want to use it in sandbox environment for testing.

I assume it has something to do with application id, I would be very grateful for step-by-step explanation

Here's how I obtain all my credentials: 
I login into my developer account.

account1.Username, account1.Password, account1.Signature 
 
- **sandbox** -> **accounts** -> I select primary receiver of the payment (business type account) -> **API Credentials** 

applicationId - "APP-80W284485P519543T" 
In the config file I specified mode as "sandbox".

I use the same config for executing the payment.

Then I want to execute following code and in payResponse I get errorId 520003 "Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect."

```
public class PermissionController : Controller
{
    private AdaptivePaymentsService _adaptivePaymentService;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.AccessToken = PayPalConfig.AccessToken;
        ViewBag.AccessTokenSecret = PayPalConfig.AccessTokenSecret;
        return View();
    }

    public PermissionController()
    {
        _adaptivePaymentService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(PayPalConfig.GetConfig());
    }

    public ActionResult GetPermission()
    {
        RequestPermissionsRequest rp = new RequestPermissionsRequest();
        rp.scope = new List<string>();
        rp.scope.Add("EXPRESS_CHECKOUT");

        Dictionary<string, string> config = PayPalConfig.GetConfig();

        rp.callback = "http://localhost:42072/Permission/GetAccessToken";

        rp.requestEnvelope = new PayPal.Permissions.Model.RequestEnvelope("en_US");

        RequestPermissionsResponse rpr = null;

        PermissionsService service = new PermissionsService(config);

        rpr = service.RequestPermissions(rp);
        string confirmPermissions = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=" + rpr.token;

        return Redirect(confirmPermissions);
    }

    public ActionResult GetAccessToken()
    {
        Uri uri = Request.Url;
        Dictionary<string, string> config = PayPalConfig.GetConfig();

        var gat = new GetAccessTokenRequest();

        gat.token = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("request_token");
        gat.verifier = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("verification_code");

        gat.requestEnvelope = new PayPal.Permissions.Model.RequestEnvelope("en_US");
        GetAccessTokenResponse gats = null;

        var service = new PermissionsService(config);
        gats = service.GetAccessToken(gat);
        _adaptivePaymentService.SetAccessToken(gats.token);
        _adaptivePaymentService.SetAccessTokenSecret(gats.tokenSecret);
        PayPalConfig.AccessToken = _adaptivePaymentService.getAccessToken();
        PayPalConfig.AccessTokenSecret = _adaptivePaymentService.getAccessTokenSecret();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult ChainedPayment()
    {
        ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList();

        receiverList.receiver = new List<Receiver>();
        Receiver secondaryReceiver = new Receiver(1.00M);
        secondaryReceiver.email = "mizerykordia6662-facilitator@gmail.com";
        receiverList.receiver.Add(secondaryReceiver);

        Receiver primaryReceiver = new Receiver(5.00M);
        primaryReceiver.email = "mizTestMerchant@test.com";
        primaryReceiver.primary = true;
        receiverList.receiver.Add(primaryReceiver);

        PayPal.AdaptivePayments.Model.RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new PayPal.AdaptivePayments.Model.RequestEnvelope("en_US");
        string actionType = "PAY";
        string returnUrl = "http://localhost:42072/Home/Index";
        string cancelUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/dotnet?cancel=true";
        string currencyCode = "USD";

        _adaptivePaymentService.SetAccessToken(PayPalConfig.AccessToken);
        _adaptivePaymentService.SetAccessTokenSecret(PayPalConfig.AccessTokenSecret);

        PayRequest payRequest = new PayRequest(requestEnvelope, actionType, 
            cancelUrl, currencyCode, receiverList, returnUrl);

        // it breaks here
        PayResponse payResponse = _adaptivePaymentService.Pay(payRequest);

        PaymentDetailsRequest paymentDetailsRequest = new PaymentDetailsRequest(new PayPal.AdaptivePayments.Model.RequestEnvelope("en-US"));
        paymentDetailsRequest.payKey = payResponse.payKey;

        SetPaymentOptionsRequest paymentOptions = new SetPaymentOptionsRequest()
            { payKey = payResponse.payKey };

        _adaptivePaymentService.SetPaymentOptions(paymentOptions);

        PaymentDetailsResponse paymentDetailsRespons = _adaptivePaymentService.PaymentDetails(paymentDetailsRequest);

        ExecutePaymentRequest exec = new ExecutePaymentRequest(new PayPal.AdaptivePayments.Model.RequestEnvelope("en-US"), paymentDetailsRequest.payKey);
        ExecutePaymentResponse response = _adaptivePaymentService.ExecutePayment(exec);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```